# How to implement a swift code to generate xml file

Tags: ios, xml, nsxmlnode

well i've tried to do some code that can do a xml file in a "well done" way, I found this code https://gist.github.com/brentdax/caaaa134c500e00efd36
and  i think is a good option to implement that i wish. but i can implementa that.

actually i implements but the error says: use of undeclared type NSXMLNode.

I tried to put it on source file, in a playgrouns on viewcontroller code file without success

I don`t know how can implement this.+

thanks in advice

Comment: Update your question with your code (at least the part relevant to the issue).

Answer (score 1):

If you want help fixing your code you need to show us that code.

Failing that, take a look at the `NSXMLParser` class. It's fairly easy to use.

### EDIT:

This is a very old thread, but rmaddy pointed out that the question was about generating XML, and my solution of using NSXMLParser will parse XML, but not generate it.

I recently found a reference to the [**XMLParsing library**](https://github.com/ShawnMoore/XMLParsing), which apparently follows the conventions of the `Codable` protocol. I suggest using that.

Comment: NSXMLParser is for parsing XML, not generating XML.

Comment: @rmaddy, You were able to tell that the OP wants to generate XML, not read it? Good on you then. I didn't get that far in understanding the question.

Comment: The question's title made it clear to me. :) And the linked file is for generating XML.

Comment: @rmaddy, Oh yeah, the title does make that pretty clear, doesn't it? :\ (Walking away, head bowed in shame...)